# Handle Node Down (being disabled) in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

Is there a way to handle the event of a Service Fabric Node going down (NodeStatus change) in C#. Possibly an event I can listen for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're running in Azure, you can use Azure Monitor Alerts to call a webhook, or a logic app to accomplish this.

For example:

> In the Monitor - Alerts (classic) pane, select +Add activity log
>   alert. On the Add activity log alert page, select or enter the
>   requested information. In Criteria, make sure that you set the
>   following values: Event category: Select Service Health. Services:
>   Select Virtual Machine Scale Sets and Virtual Machines. Type: Select
>   Planned maintenance.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-maintenance-notifications#notification-and-alerts-in-the-portal) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview).

Comment: Thanks, I need a local development solution.

Comment: Also, from your understanding, there is no way for C# code to handle some sort of Node Down event or notification? Should I stop looking?

Comment: I'm not aware of functionality that is built-in, but you could probably write a service that monitors the health / presence of nodes. Somewhat similar in approach to what I mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899694/5946937